# debugging changes result Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit

I'm wondering something about debugging and what it means.

Currently developping a program that watches a directory and when something changes in the directory, it runs all the tests that it can find in the same directory.

So, I test what happens if you change the tests? I find that when I have 20 tests that should fail, and I change one of them to succeed, the program finds and runs all the tests and reports 20 failed tests. It doesn't use the new test, which is slightly odd.

Now, when I go through the program with a debugger, it does detect the new test!

How come the results change when using a debugger? It is the default debugger of Eclipse.
The program watches the directory using a WatchService and runs and collects the tests using JUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall answer your question as I understand it.
The debugger in eclipse is designed for making complex applications, like GUI's or apps like your own.
The debugger allows you to change the code of a program **in real time**. It is designed for you to be able to edit an application, and see what your doing with it, IE changing a window size, ETC.
Each debugger run is a clean build. Try cleaning the builds of your eclipse project, this may be creating the problem, as the compiler is logging the data and expecting you to input a certain answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you say. So when I do a regular execution, and change (even unrelated parts of) the program during run time it won't be used. Any idea how I can adjust it so it is? Cleaning the builds doesn't do it.

Comment: Again, if I understand what you are getting at, the only way to edit code and have it update in real time is the debugger. The only thing I can think of would be the clean build. Can you provide some code on what is supposed to pass and what fails, and on how the compiler/JVM tests this?

Comment: Yes, I'm basically looking for Hot Code Replacement. I can't really provide code to easily solve it, but I will talk this over with my instructor (who mentioned something about this). Thanks for your help!